# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException after 2s

Tags: mysql, jdbc, dropwizard, hikaricp, jdbi

I am using drop-wizard and mysql 5.6. Whenever a query takes more than 2s I keep getting this exception.

```
org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,002 milliseconds ago.
```

I have set @QueryTimeOut as 4s. What can be the cause for the connection to be interrupted?

Comment: Please post a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I had set socketTimeout in connection url and forgot about it.